# How to get the name menu in navigation when I click it in Angular

Tags: html, angular, admin

I have an issue with my Angular project. I can't get only one component of menu and put it on nav to show which menu is clicked.

This is my `header.component.html`

```
     <mat-nav-list>
      <mat-list-item>
        <a style="color: white;" *ngFor="let menuitem of menuItems.getMenuitem()">{{ menuitem.name }}</a>
      </mat-list-item>
     </mat-nav-list>
```

This is my `header.component.ts`

```
import { MediaMatcher } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  Component,
  NgZone,
  OnDestroy,
  ViewChild,
  HostListener,
  Directive,
  AfterViewInit
} from '@angular/core';
import { MenuItems } from '../../../shared/menu-items/menu-items';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: []
})

export class AppHeaderComponent implements OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
  mobileQuery: MediaQueryList;

  private _mobileQueryListener: () => void;

  constructor(
    changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    media: MediaMatcher,
    public menuItems: MenuItems
  ) {
    this.mobileQuery = media.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)');
    this._mobileQueryListener = () => changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.mobileQuery.addListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.mobileQuery.removeListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {}


}
```

This is my `menu-items.ts` when i get menu names

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


export interface BadgeItem {
  type: string;
  value: string;
}

export interface Menu {
  state: string;
  name: string;
  type: string;
  icon: string;
  badge?: BadgeItem[];
}

const MENUITEMS = [
  { state: 'home', type: 'link', name: 'HOME', icon: 'home' },
  { state: 'dashboard', name: 'DASHBOARD', type: 'link', icon: 'dashboard' },
  { state: 'organizzazioni', type: 'link', name: 'ORGANIZZAZIONI', icon: 'domain' },
  { state: 'registri', type: 'link', name: 'REGISTRI', icon: 'assignment' },
  {
    state: 'aprovazioni', type: 'link', name: 'APROVAZIONI', icon: 'view_headline', badge: [
      { type: 'red', value: '1' }]
  },
  { state: 'impatto', type: 'link', name: 'IMPATTO', icon: 'tab' },
  { state: 'informative', type: 'link', name: 'INFORMATIVE', icon: 'web' },
  { state: 'violazioni', type: 'link', name: 'VIOLAZIONI', icon: 'vertical_align_center' },
];

@Injectable()
export class MenuItems {
  getMenuitem(): Menu[] {
    return MENUITEMS;
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How about adding a click event and react on it in the navigation bar:

```
 <mat-nav-list>
      <mat-list-item>
        <a style="color: white;" *ngFor="let menuitem of menuItems.getMenuitem()" (click)="menuItemClick(menuitem)">{{ menuitem.name }}</a>
      </mat-list-item>
     </mat-nav-list>
```

Comment: It seems that is not solving my problem. I got an error "Identifier 'menuItemClick' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member"

Comment: Just add the method 'menuItemClick' to the 'AppHeaderComponent' component and you should be good

Comment: Maybe I dont know how to do but I cant fix the issue.

Comment: it just means that "menuItemCLick()" is a function _you_ have to write in component.ts body where you can put your logic. i.e. just next to `ngAfterViewInit() {}`. 

BTW, that's a normal event binding and it's pretty basic, same as, saying, `(click)="onClick()"`  -->  `function onCLick() { console.log('clicked')}`

Answer (score 1):

Add click event on html file (... Is portion of your code)

`<a ... (click)="handleMenuClick(menuitem)"></a>`

In your header ts file add method

`handleMenuClick (item) {
   alert(item.name)
 }`

So inside that function get value, and do any desired task to change UI based on this selected item, I have just added alert to show current item

Answer (score 0):

You need to define that method in your controller file

Comment: Maybe I dont know how to do but I cant fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add menuItemClick method to your menuItem class and this method should take the clicked item as a parameter then handle item click event in your html

Something like that

```
export class MenuItems {
  getMenuitem(): Menu[] {
   return MENUITEMS;
  }
  menuItemClick(MenuItem: Menu){
   // Do something
 }
}
```

And in your html

```
 <mat-nav-list>
  <mat-list-item>
    <a style="color: white;" *ngFor="let 
       menuitem of menuItems.getMenuitem()" (click)="menuItems.menueItemClick(menuitem)">{{ menuitem.name }}</a>
  </mat-list-item>
 </mat-nav-list>
```

Comment: Im new in Angular and Im not familiarised with names you write before. Can you tell me more where to go and which codes to put

Comment: Still the same thing. It show all the names of menus like the photo above.

Comment: I think your loop should be over the mat-list-item not the anchor tag